# mongod shutting down with code:62

Tags: ruby, mongodb

After installing an older version of ruby for a ruby on rails project, my mongod demon wont run anymore for my node.js project. Not sure if these are related, but nothing else has changed. I've tried to upgrade ruby to latest and it did not fix the problem. I've also uninstalled and re-installed mongo with brew and it did not fix the problem. Any help and hints are greatly appreciated. Here's my output...

```
sudo mongod
Password:
2019-03-27T12:45:26.039-0400 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=36533 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Aleksandras-MBP.fios-router.home
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.3
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-03-27T12:45:26.051-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-03-27T12:45:26.052-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7680M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-03-27T12:45:26.804-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553705126:804421][36533:0x11afba5c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 50/768
2019-03-27T12:45:26.925-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553705126:925148][36533:0x11afba5c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 50 through 51
2019-03-27T12:45:27.004-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553705127:4441][36533:0x11afba5c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 51 through 51
2019-03-27T12:45:27.073-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553705127:73517][36533:0x11afba5c0], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-03-27T12:45:27.207-0400 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2019-03-27T12:45:27.775-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-03-27T12:45:27.904-0400 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an upgrade to 4.0; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2019-03-27T12:45:27.904-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-03-27T12:45:27.904-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-03-27T12:45:27.905-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2019-03-27T12:45:28.005-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Downgrading WiredTiger datafiles.
2019-03-27T12:45:28.255-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553705128:255245][36533:0x11afba5c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 51/11264
2019-03-27T12:45:28.389-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553705128:389878][36533:0x11afba5c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 51 through 52
2019-03-27T12:45:28.473-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553705128:473028][36533:0x11afba5c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 52 through 52
2019-03-27T12:45:28.533-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553705128:533500][36533:0x11afba5c0], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-03-27T12:45:29.887-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2019-03-27T12:45:29.888-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-03-27T12:45:29.888-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62
```

Comment: You should read error messages, the problem and its solution are written in clear: `IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an upgrade to 4.0; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv for more details.`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, this is what I did to fix...

```
brew uninstall mongo
brew install mongo
```

remove all WiredTiger files in /data/db

```
sudo mongod
```

Hope it helps someone!